# How *environmentally* durable are pet-resistant screens?

Tags: screens

I've got some damaged wire screens on our porch, and since I have two dogs I've been replacing them with pet-resistant screens made from what appears to be a nylon mesh coated with plastic/rubber.

So far, they seem to work great. They are *physically* quite durable due to the fact that they stretch some when the dogs jump on them, and this little bit of give keeps them from easily getting holes punched in them.

However, rubbers and plastics can be prone to [photodegradation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photodegradation), and my porch screens are in direct sunlight for most of the day. Does anyone have any experience/knowledge of how durable pet-resistant screens are from an *environmental* standpoint? How long can I typically expect them to last before they start to break down due to the elements (mainly sun)?

Answer (score 1):

They are typically made of vinyl. Some people are stating here that it last them about 5 years so far. I'd expect 5-10 years. After 10 years, it probably will be brittle anyways. Just keep the chemicals away and wash with water only.